# Did purging occur during the American revolution?

Tags: american-revolution

Every nation that has revolutionized in the last 150 years has undergone major turmoil including the jailing and execution of dissidents. France and Russian revolutions were both famously violent transitions.

There had to be rival factions including loyal Monarchists at the time. How were they managed by the Revolutionaries?

Comment: Have you checked [Loyalist (American Revolution)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loyalist_(American_Revolution)#Emigration_from_the_United_States)? Also, please [take a tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at [how to ask a question](https://history.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: FYI the French Revolution gained a violent reputation because of the guillotine, but it doesn't really deserve that reputation. A few hundred lost their heads in Paris, sure, but the real killings occurred in the rest of France (chiefly in Vendee, where they sank boats full of people because the guillotine couldn't keep up) and on the battlefield. When the army repressed Paris insurrections during 19th century, there were sometimes more deaths per day in Paris than there had been deaths by guillotine in Paris over the course of the entire French Revolution.

Comment: Yes.  What research have you done?  Iirc, the issue of compensation for Tories was not formally settled till after the Civil War.  There is good material in legal histories of the era and in communities that migrated to Canada.  Excellent, important question, but it would be stronger with preliminary research.

Comment: What became of the Loyalists is one of those things I think us US History experts know about, but probably isn't well taught in schools (outside of perhaps Canada). So this seems a legit question to me.

Comment: No. They didn't have enough excess food for purging to be useful.  Perhaps you meant to ask about "purges"?